# How to update Database while checking checkbox with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I am trying to update a value in DB while checking checkbox (1 or 0) with jquerys $.post or $.ajax. I would really appreciate some help. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
     <?php
    $yesno = (bool)$baner['noti'];
    $checked = ($yesno) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';  
     ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value="1" id="myonoffswitch" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
   <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("#myonoffswitch").click(function(){
        $.post("notification.php");
        })
    });
```

**notification.php**

```
connections stuffs...

$yesno = ( isset($_POST['onoffswitch']) ) ? 1 : 0;
$sql = "UPDATE baner SET noti='$yesno'";
```

Comment: What seems to go wrong? It doesn't appear that you're sending any data with your post request. You might find the documentation for [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) helpful, especially the [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#entry-examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it.  you just need to read your checkbox state and send it back with your POST request.

```
$(function(){
    $("#myonoffswitch").click(function(){
        var isOn = $("#myonoffswitch").prop("checked");
        $.post("notification.php", { 'onoffswitch': isOn }, function (result) {
            //handle success here
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I am getting error on this line: var isOn  $("#myonoffswitch").prop("checked");

Comment: I think there is missing an equal sign. But it wont work for me with or without. Any Idea? When I am changing manually to 0 it change the first time when I click to 1, but It wont go back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with ***`$.ajax`***. *It is used widely for update data without redirect page.*

```
$("#myonoffswitch").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       var onoffswitch=$('#myonoffswitch').val();
       type: "POST",
       url: "notification.php", //Relative or absolute path to notification.php file
       data: {onoffswitch: onoffswitch},
       success: function(response) {
                content.html(response);
       }
    });  

});
```

***notification.php***

```
connections stuff...

$yesno = ( isset($_POST['onoffswitch']) ) ? 1 : 0;
$sql = "UPDATE baner SET noti='$yesno'";
```